# Need help doing multi-threading in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm having trouble getting this function to compile as a thread. Can someone help me out? Thanks

```
class HWCLayerVersion1 : public Iterable<HWCLayerVersion1, hwc_layer_1_t> {
    struct hwc_composer_device_1* mHwc;
...
status_t HWComposer::acquire(int disp) {
    LOG_FATAL_IF(disp >= VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_ID_BASE);
    struct arg_struct *args = (struct arg_struct *) args;
    args->disp = disp;
    args->value = 0;
    args->h = mHwc;
    pthread_t some_thread;

    status_t ret;
    if (mHwc) {
        int hi = pthread_create(&some_thread, NULL, &mHwc->blank, &args);
    }
    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Inside hwcomposer.h:

```
typedef struct hwc_composer_device_1 {
    struct hw_device_t common;
int (*blank)(struct hwc_composer_device_1* dev, int disp, int blank);
```

And in a separate .cpp file, hwc_composer_device_1 is

```
static int hwc_blank(struct hwc_composer_device_1* dev, int dpy, int blank)
```

I get the following error (one line but I broke it up into 3 lines):

```
error: cannot convert 'int (**)(hwc_composer_device_1*, int, int)'
to 'void* (*)(void*)' for argument '3'
to 'int pthread_create(pthread_t*, const pthread_attr_t*, void* (*)(void*), void*)'
```

Comment: You need a function with the appropriate signature: `void *(*)(void *)`. An example: `void *do_work(void *args) { }`. You can create such a function that performs the appropriate casting and passes the arguments to your original function.

Comment: Use [`std::thread`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/). There's nothing wrong with `pthread` though, but `std::thread` is part of the standard library. Since it's a part of C++, it's guaranteed to have an implementation on every platform. Even if you don't plan to port your code to other platforms, you'd still be better off using something that's part of the standard library, rather than something that's platform-dependant (in most cases at least). (actually the `std::thread` implementation uses `pthread` on most platforms, but you still get extra security and stuff).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't have the right signature for use with `pthread`. One option is to create a function like this:

```
void *do_blank(void *args) {
     struct arg_struct *blank_args = (struct arg_struct *)args;
     return hwc_blank(blank_args->h, blank_args->disp, blank_args->value);
}
```

Then you could pass it to `pthread` like this:

```
if (mHwc) {
    int hi = pthread_create(&some_thread, NULL, do_blank, &args);
}
```

Whenever you retrieve the return value from this thread, you will need to cast the result as an integer.